# What level should I cluster at?

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, clustered-standard-errors

I have panel data over two years for 8000 observations (all over the age of 21). 2000 of the observations are siblings.

If I have cluster by family, I have 6000 clusters. If I cluster by individuals, I have 8000 clusters.

I am checking the effect of gambling on earnings. Which level do you think I should cluster on?

Answer (score 2):

At what level you should cluster your standard errors depends on what observations you think are conditionally independent given your regressors.

For example, if the earnings of siblings are linked in ways not accounted for by your regressors, then you really don't have 8000 independent observations. You have closer to 6000 and should cluster your standard errors at the family level.

Comment: Hi , thank you for the reply. I don't mean to bother you but could you please provide an example of what sort of things might not be accounted for that affect individuals on a family level? I only ask because this is a fixed effects and the only unobservables I can think of are time-invariant (which are taken away by FE).

Comment: @F4N no worries. The general concern is that the error term in `earnings_{i,t} = ... + e_{i,t}` is that the `e_{i,t}` term is correlated within a family. Just off the top of my head, it may be time invariant unobservables (eg. genetics) or even time variant unobservables (eg. success/failure of a family business). To the extent that everyone in the same town rise and fall together, you could be even more conservative and cluster on region. You can almost ALWAYS tell a story that would make error terms correlated. Don't let the search for the perfect stop you from doing something reasonable.

Comment: A random technical point to be aware of too is that mathematically, clustering on the fixed effects variable is equivalent to heteroskedasticity robust standard errors.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your objective is. If you want to see the effect on individual, then use individual clusters (btw you generally refer to clusters with more than 1 data points).

However, if you want to see how gambling effect a family level, then use only the 2000 family clusters. Questions like If one sibling is addicted, does it spread to other siblings as well?